# ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter implemenations in micronaut

Tags: filter, jax-rs, micronaut

Hey i am new to micronaut , and wanted to implement some filters like ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter that are present in JAX-RS.

I know that HttpServerFilter is used a lot in micronaut and like other filters it can intercept http calls , but i am looking to find a way to implement filters that specific in either : incoming HttpRequest or outgoing request !

Thanks a lot for

I have made a filter but i am not sure how to specify the filter to either looks only incoming request of outgoing request like ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter.

Answer (score 0):

For outgoing you could use the HTTP Client Filter
https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-http-client-maven-java.html#http-client-filter

and for incoming i guess the HTTP Server Filter should do
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/filter/HttpServerFilter.html

https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-multitenancy-propagation-gradle-groovy.html#http-filter-cookie-redirect its groovy but i think that shows how to use them.

Comment: Hey ok , i got it that we can use the HttpServerFilter as a filter for the incoming request , but what i am little confuse is that ->
when server will process the request and response back to the client to the same request, then at that time : do we use the client filter at Server side or there is some other approach in micronaut ? like we have containerReponseFilter inside the Jersey !

Comment: i am not shure if i understand you correctly .. but server filter ist for incoming requests and client filter for outgoing requests !!! its all about request direction .. not response .. so i think you could use the http server filter to modify your servers response if you want to

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply , really appreciated. 

My doubt is related to Repose filter . Here, in the below example i have explained it in detail.

Lets say we two service ‘A’ and ‘B’.
1. ‘A’ sends the request to ‘B’ :  A ---> B  : to filter that request we use HttpeServerFilter , Now after filter logic is implemented , the mutated request will goes to ‘B’ .
2 . After which ‘B’ will send some response to ‘A’ . So i want to know, how to add filter for that response from ‘B’ ---> ‘A’

So i want to manipulate that reponse using the filters in micronaut .

Comment: For sending a request from A to B you use a client filter cause A is the client and B the server. And to modify the response of B you use a server filter, cause B is a Server for the request. But if B needs to call C you need a client filter in B side